# ASP.NET MVC Bind Attribute on Method instead of Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm aware that you can do this:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething([Bind(Exclude = "CreationDate")] Item item)
{ /*...*/ }
```

However, I found that you can also attach that Bind attribute on top of the method, e.g.

```
[Bind(Exclude = "CreationDate")] 
public ActionResult DoSomething(Item item)
{ /*...*/ }
```

Does this have the exact same effect? What if you bind to more than one parameter?

Comment: I can't get the second example ([Bind] on the method itself) to compile.  Are you sure you're using System.Web.Mvc.BindAttribute instead of another custom attribute called [Bind] with looser usage restrictions?

Comment: Bind attribute just work on the class and parameter declarations

Comment: It looks like you can apply the Bind attribute to individual parameters.  For example, if you had a view that included two instances of Person, one prefixed with "Manager" and the other with "Lackey", you could use something like: public ActionResult Flog([Bind(Prefix="Manager")] Person manager, [Bind(Prefix="Lackey")] Person designatedVictim)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the `Bind` attribute is no longer applicable to functions; it is only valid attached to a parameter or class. When attempting to utilize the attribute on a method, an error presents: `Attribute 'Bind' is not valid on this declaration type. It is valid on 'class, parameter' declarations.`

---

The second form is the one that I have seen more commonly.  To my knowledge, both forms do exactly the same thing.

The Exclude option takes a comma-separated list of attributes. The Exclude list simply excludes one or more parameters from binding; it has no effect on the remaining parameters.

Example:

```
[Bind(Exclude="ID, Name")]
```

Comment: The second form won't compile. The Bind attribute's allowed targets are class and parameters. [BindAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.bindattribute.aspx)