# Is there a simple way to avoid nulls being saved to the Database when using Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC3, Razor, C#, .NET4, EF5.

I have a number of situations where I am editing the domain model directly, and yes I realise that I should be using View Models :) However for the short term I am hoping I can get a solution to my problem whereby I am getting nulls being saved to the DB, where those fields are not specified as Hidden Fields in the forms. I realise this is to do with the Model Binding behaviour.

My Edit Action:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        StdOrg myOrg = db.StdOrg.Single(s => s.Id == id);
        return View(myOrg);
    }
```

Lets assume my View has 5 fields on it:

```
Name
Address1
Address2
Address3
Address4
```

Now for my Post Edit Action:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(StdOrg myOrg)
 {
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
     db.StdOrg.Attach(myOrg);
     db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myOrg, EntityState.Modified);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
 return View(myOrg);
 }
```

Now my Table record has 10 columns in it, and columns 6-10 has values.

```
Name
Address1
Address2
Address3
Address4
Terms
EmployeeNo
Code
Active
SetUpDate
```

When I save the form, columns 6-10 ie Terms etc. get set to null. Now I realise this is due to the fact that I am not specifying them as hidden fields in my View and therefore MVC Model Binding is assuming these are null.

Is there a practical way around this, rather than specifying all columns in the form which I would rather not do for security reasons.

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT

My attempt which does not seem to work:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Name,Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4")] StdOrg myOrg)
```

Thoughts.... ???

IN CONCLUSION

For those interested I ended up using the "Value Injector" which is the other "Automapper" for which I wrote a simple matching routine to prevent nulls being set, and also to exclude navigation properties as well. Very useful Mapper.

One still really needs to implement ViewModels since these seem the only way to identify which of the classes properties are in the View, unless one can get Bind attribute working which I could not.
Otherwise even with a mapper one cannot reset a View field to null, since the mapper will ensure that it is ignored !! It cannot tell between View Properties and others in the domain class, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the [BindAttribute](http://ittecture.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/tip-of-the-day-199-asp-net-mvc-defining-model-binding-explicitly/), you can simply exclude or include the fields for that particular action (which is always good practice, someone could manipulate the ID field on the POST and modify a different value).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419434/asp-net-mvc-bind-attribute-on-method-instead-of-parameter) for an example

Comment: Thank you for this. This is a new one on me, and looks very useful. Just doing some reading now. I think I will need to use the "Include" variant since the table contains many more columns.

Comment: Found a nice article on this at OdeToCode: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/03/11/complete-guide-to-mass-assignment-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx. Long term, View Models seem much the best route. Thanks.

Comment: See Edit. It seems to not work. I have also seen other posts about this possible not working. Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry to unaccept, just could not get it to work. Perhaps you may have some bright ideas.

Comment: Reaccepted.....:) Still not working :(, but I think ViewModels are the way to go. Just read Darin's view on this. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Despite putting Exclude stuff:

```
[Bind(Exclude = "PropertyName,PropertyType")]
public class Filter {

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public Type PropertyType { get; set; }
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Match { get; set; }
}
```

those properties seem to be ovewritten with NULL, when I call this method from model (note: PropertyName and PropertyType are not and must not be present in markup! They are filled once in the code, before making markup)

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual PartialViewResult LoadFiltered(string entityType, IDictionary<string, Filter> filters)
```

And when no elements selected (all filters are disabled in interface) - I get two elements, having "controller" and "action" as keys. What the... ??